# Prisma JS soft delete with PrismaClient().$extends

Tags: prisma

This is my prisma init on my nextjs app,  I'm implementing soft delete on the delete query
I just have no idea what to do since on the documentation is using $use. Please insight, thanks

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prismaClientSingleton = () => {
  return new PrismaClient().$extends({
    name: "name",
    query: {
      leaveRequest: {
        async delete({ model, operation, args, query }) {
          console.log(model, operation, args, query);

          // return await model.update...; << NOT WORK
          // operation = "update"; << NOT WORK
          /* 

          1. replace the method from delete to update 
          2. configure the where clause
          3. execute the query
          */

          return await query(args);
        },
      },
    },
  });
};

declare global {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-var
  var prisma: undefined | ReturnType<typeof prismaClientSingleton>;
}

const prisma = globalThis.prisma ?? prismaClientSingleton();

export default prisma;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") globalThis.prisma = prisma;
```

Answer (score 0):

Prisma does not directly support soft deletes. However, you can implement soft deletes by adding a deletedAt field to your model and using it.

First, add a deletedAt field to your Prisma schema:

```
model LeaveRequest {
  // ...other fields
  deletedAt DateTime? @default(null)
}
```

Then, modify the delete method to call the update method that sets the deletedAt field to the current time instead:

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prismaClientSingleton = () => {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient();

  prisma.leaveRequest.delete = async (args) => {
    return await prisma.leaveRequest.update({
      where: args.where,
      data: { deletedAt: new Date() },
    });
  };

  return prisma;
};

declare global {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-var
  var prisma: undefined | ReturnType<typeof prismaClientSingleton>;
}

const prisma = globalThis.prisma ?? prismaClientSingleton();

export default prisma;
```

Finally, when you call the delete method, it actually sets the deletedAt field to the current time.

This makes it appear as if the record has been deleted, but it actually remains in the database. This is how you can implement soft deletes.